# Re-Install R with Shared library option in CentOS 6.5

Tags: r, installation, shared-libraries, yum, centos6.5

Operating System:CentOS 6.5 (64 bit)
R version: 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk"

I did the R installation using yum:

```
# su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'
# yum update --disablerepo=epel 
# yum install R
```

I also downloaded and installed R-Studio server:

```
# wget http://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-0.98.507-x86_64.rpm
# sudo yum install –nogpgcheck rstudio-server-0.98.507-x86_64.rpm
```

Further I had installed several R packages (especially rJava & RHive).
The issue I have is specifically with rhive.init() and related functions.

In the putty session things are fine.
But when accessed over the R-Console via browser , rhive.init() fails with the following message, even after setting the variable HIVE_HOME at the host.
error:

> library(RHive)
>   Loading required package: rJava
>   rhive.init()
>   [1] FALSE

Looks like the issue could be because R wasn't installed with shared library.
Searching the web provided inputs to download tarballs, unzip, configure, build, make and install.

Since I've already installed R (using `yum install`), is there anyway or specifically any option to `yum install`, so that R could re-installed with the 'Shared library' option.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `./configure --help` then you can see the option below:

```
--enable-R-shlib build the shared/dynamic library 'libR' [no]
```